# Missing number when using exercise package

Tags: packages, exercises

I'm trying to use the exercise package. Based on [this document](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf), this should work:

```
\documentclass[
]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[printsolution=true]{exercises}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{Exercise}[title={Euler’s constant}, difficulty=2, label=ex1,
                 origin={P.Paelw}]
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

However, the compiler tells me that the environment `Exercise` isn't defined so I tried this:

```
\documentclass[
]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[printsolution=true]{exercises}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{exercise}[title={Euler’s constant}, difficulty=2, label=ex1,
                 origin={P.Paelw}]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

I get this error: `! Missing number, treated as zero.`.

What is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The package whose documentation you linked is `exercise`, not `exercises`.
2. The option `printsolution=true` is not present in the package.
   The default behaviour is to show both the exercises and the answers
   (with `noanswer` you can hide all the answers of a document).

This works:

```
\documentclass[
]{report}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} <-- no more needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}

\begin{document}


\begin{Exercise}[title={Euler’s constant}, difficulty=2, label=ex1,
                 origin={P.Paelw}]
This is my exercise text.
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
This is my exercise solution text.
\end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

I added `lastexercise` so, if no references is given for an answer, then the answer is supposed
to refer to the last exercise (see the [package documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf)).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Then why am I able to use ``\begin{Exercise}foo\end{Exercise}`` without any issue?

Comment: @Dunno There is another package: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/exercises/exercises.pdf, but it is not the one whose documentation you linked

Comment: Sorry, your MWE throw five errors: `! Package keyval Error: lastexercise undefined`,  `! LaTeX Error: Environment Exercise undefined.`,  `! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{Exercise}.`, `! LaTeX Error: Environment Answer undefined.` and `! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{Answer}.
`. I have installed only `exercise` package. Do should install `exercises` package too?

Comment: @Zarko It works for me, with `exercise` only. Are you sure you're not compiling with `exercises`?

Comment: Unfortunately exist more `exercise` packages. I have stored one of Mark Wooding author (from 2001) in `localtexmf` forlder.  After deleting it your MWE works fine! Sorry for noise.

Comment: @Zarko The existence of both `exercise` and `exercises` is also a bit confusing :D